# When do you create Leads for Form submissions - Sales Cloud

Tags: leads, sales-cloud, form

We are using multiple forms in our website, some are contact us forms, some are products related to specific products / services. We are using Salesforce Sales Cloud , and are not currently using Marketing Cloud or Pardot. The questions is how to best utilize Salesforce objects to have all the form information in our Salesforce instance.

We used to create a lead whenever a form is submitted. The idea is that this lead can then be handled by the appropriate team for lead qualification, and possible conversion to Opportunity, etc.
Problems: Each lead object only contains info from one form. A lot of leads generated for the same email, since one email can fill multiple forms, that would be handled one by one. This could also be considered to be lead duplication.

Idea 1: We are examining whether we should be creating a Lead on the first ever form submitted for an email, and then on following forms create a related object (looking at Tasks / Cases ). This way, we would have a Lead record, with multiple tasks under it, each task being a submitted form. The related objects could have multiple record types with different fields, one record type for a contact us form, one for the "Interested in product X" form, etc.

Idea 2: Create many custom fields in the Lead object. All form information would be transferred into the respective Lead fields.
Problems: Bloated Lead object. If user submits multiple forms with the same fields, we would be losing some of that information.

Looking forward to hearing your thoughts. How does your org capture form information in Salesforce Sales Cloud, and how do you handle lead creation/ avoid lead duplication?

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest solution would be to create some Duplication Rules (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.managing_duplicates_overview.htm&type=5) so that when one of your Sales agents opens one of the Leads, they immediately see and are able to merge the others together into one Record with all of the information.  This would require the least amount of technical ability and time to implement.

Additionally, you can create some before save automations via Flow or APEX that runs when these records are created that searches for any already created Leads that are from the same person and adds the info to the existing Lead and cancels the creation of the new one.  This would take some development experience and add to the complication of your org but require the least amount of manual work for your Sales Agents.

Comment: Hello Fencer thank you for your response. What is the recommended way to capture all this info under the same Object however? Is it to have every single form field we use to  be a field in our Lead Object? 
Let's say a Contact us form has fields: Email, Name, and Message.
and an "Interested in product X" form has fields: Email, Name, Question, Type of Use, Wish To Speak with a Sales Person.

Would all our Leads then also need to have these fields: Email, Name, Message, Question, Type of Use, Wish To Speak with a Sales Person ?

Comment: @OrestisF. - All similary functional fields on each form would populate the same fields for Leads. For example; Email on an "Interested in product X" form and Email in a Contact Us form would both fill out the standard Email field.  Your duplicate rule would then match on that Email field with an Exact match so that any Leads with the exact same Email would be flagged as duplicates and your Sales reps would see them listed out in the Duplicates Related List for merging.  They would then merge them together into One Lead.

Comment: Ok, let's say a user submits two forms with some of the same fields, such as "Interested in Product" . They would submit one form for Product X, and one for Product Y. How would we effectively collect that data in one Lead Object? Only via using a multi select picklist for the "Interested in Product Field", correct? 
What if all our forms have a free text field called "Additional Comments", and a user submits 2 forms with comments, how would we store that in Salesforce?